# ASP.NET 5 Controller method can't receive JSON POST, ASP.NET 4 controller method does

Tags: datatables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been tearing my hair out over this one. I have two projects one running `ASP.NET 4` and the other `ASP.NET 5 RC1`

The `ASP.NET 5` project controller received `POST` method input parameters are all default and not the values as sent from the webpage.

To narrow down the problem I simplified the controllers `POST` methods in both projects

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DataHandler(int Draw)
{
    //above Draw variable not set
}
```

and put a break point on the method to catch the variable `Draw`. The webpage sends a JSON post with a value of 1 for the `Draw` parameter. However in ASP.NET 5 that values is 0 (default) and other parameters I send are null instead of having values. In 'ASP.NET 4' it is correct.

I am using `jquery datatables` and the same code as used in [this](https://www.echosteg.com/jquery-datatables-asp.net-mvc5-server-side) `ASP.NET 4` project

```
var oTable = $('#datatab').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": '/Home/DataHandler',
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'data': function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
    },
    "dom": 'frtiS',
    "scrollY": 500,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "scroller": {
        loadingIndicator: false
    },
    "processing": true,
    "paging": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "columns": [
   { "data": "Name" },
   { "data": "City" },
   { "data": "Postal" },
   { "data": "Email" },
   { "data": "Company" },
   { "data": "Account" },
   { "data": "CreditCard" }
    ],
    "order": [0, "asc"]
});
```

I used `Fiddler` and compared the `JSON` sent by both project to the controller and the `JSON` content posted to the `/Home/DataHandler` for both are the exact same  i.e. `Draw=1`.

> {"draw":1,"columns":[{"data":"Name","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"City","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"Postal","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"Email","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"Company","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"Account","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":"CreditCard","name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}],"order":[{"column":0,"dir":"asc"}],"start":0,"length":126,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}

Things I tried.

- I used the same `html table` contents and above code `.js` file between projects
- Set my controller input parameter to lowercase e.g. `draw`
- Compare the `JSON` `POST` data in fiddler is the same
- Put a breakpoint on the `POST` method input variable to catch the value as soon as it is posted

Comment: Try removing `contentType` and `data` from the `ajax` section of the DataTable setup.

Comment: Try adding the `[FromBody]` attribute as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34088290/1836935)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call

Replace `return data = JSON.stringify(data)` with the following:

```
return data.Draw = JSON.stringify(data)
```