# Controller not being invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have basic stock standard `ASP.Net 5 (ASP NET Core 1) MVC 6 (MVC Core 1)` controller with a single method that is causing me grief.

Here is the method in question:

```
// Get the table data
[HttpPost("data/{requestedTable}")]
public IActionResult GetTableData(string requestedTable, [FromForm] DataTableData post)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"About to process {requestedTable}");
    _logger.LogInformation($"Draw {post.Draw}, Start {post.Start}");
    if (!SQL.ValidTable(requestedTable))
    {
        return new ErrorObjectResult("Invalid table name specified");
    }

    var count = post.Length;
    var start = post.Start;
    var search = post.Search.Value;
    var draw = post.Draw + 1;

    var recordsTotal = new SQL()
            .WithCount()
            .AllData(requestedTable)
            .FirstOrDefault()["COUNT"];
    var recordsFiltered = new SQL()
            .WithCount()
            .WithSearch(search)
            .WithNavigation()
            .AllData(requestedTable)
            .FirstOrDefault()["COUNT"];
    var data = new SQL()
            .WithLimit(count, start)
            .WithSearch(search)
            .WithNavigation()
            .OrderBy(OrderHelper.Convert(post))
            .EnableDataTable()
            .AllData(requestedTable);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Got: {recordsTotal}, {recordsFiltered}, {data.Count()}");

    return new CustomObjectResult(new {
        draw = draw,
        recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered,
        data = data
    });
}
```

It works 100% fine on my dev system (Windows 10 Pro, VS 2015 w/ IIS Express, DNVM 1.0.0-rc1-update1).

However, when I run it on Windows Server 2012 R2 through a VM, I will get 1 successful request for about 10-20 failed requests.

Here is an example log that I will receive:

```
<!-- GOOD REQUEST -->
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://<removed>/api/backend/datatable/data/AncillaryShiftReport application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 2266
info: ProdManSys.Middleware.AuthRemapping[0]
      Auth remap starting
info: ProdManSys.Middleware.AuthRemapping[0]
      SID is currently S-1-5-21-xxxxx....
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method ProdManSys.Controllers.Api.Backend.DataTableController.GetTableData with arguments (AncillaryShiftReport, ProdManSys.Controllers.Api.Backend.Helpers.DataTableData) - ModelState is Valid'
info: ProdManSys.Controllers.Api.Backend.DataTableController[0]
      About to process AncillaryShiftReport
info: ProdManSys.Controllers.Api.Backend.DataTableController[0]
      Draw 1, Start 0
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0.0016ms 200 
info: ProdManSys.Controllers.Api.Backend.DataTableController[0]
      Got: 18, 18, 10
<!-- BAD REQUEST -->
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://<removed>/api/backend/datatable/data/AncillaryShiftReport application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 2266
info: ProdManSys.Middleware.AuthRemapping[0]
      Auth remap starting
info: ProdManSys.Middleware.AuthRemapping[0]
      SID is currently S-1-5-21-xxxxx....
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0ms 200
```

Has anyone encountered similar / Have any suggested fixes that might resolve this / Have any debug hints related to this?

Comment: please check the below post. Not sure whether it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985520/asp-net-5-controller-method-cant-receive-json-post-asp-net-4-controller-method

Comment: @BalaSakthis giving it a shot, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @BalaSakthis you legend! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this issue, there seems to be something wrong with `[FromForm]`, changing this to `[FromBody]` and converting it to JSON with respective type successfully resolved this issue for me.

As per @BalaSakthis, the following question resolved my issue somewhat: [ASP.NET 5 Controller method can't receive JSON POST, ASP.NET 4 controller method does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985520/asp-net-5-controller-method-cant-receive-json-post-asp-net-4-controller-method)